# Find Device with dynamic ip on domain

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, usb, domain

I am using a device from National Instruments (myRIO) it can be configured either using wireless or usb. I want to configure it to use over wireless network without connecting it over usb first to get the ip address. However the problem is that the campus wireless network (Eduroam) cannot provide static ip. Is there a way to find specific devices on wireless network (unknown ip) such as myRIO?

Comment: If you have access to a host on the same network segment or subnet, you can check its ARP cache after connecting the new device.

Comment: Also, if you have access to the DHCP server you can check its logs.

Comment: If have access to devices host name and MAC is it possible to do a specific targeted search? There are over thousand devices/computers on the same network. Software that needs to access the device (LabVIEW) can sometimes find it by host name but this doesn't work all the time

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** Locate it in the arp cache

As you do not specify what OS you're using, I'll presume a linux build, as these tools and procedures have equivalents in other OSes.

1. First you need to scan the network, so that your arp cache knows of every other device on the network. On linux, this can easily be done with nmap (There's a windows port named zenmap which works the same way): `nmap -sP 192.168.10.0/24`. Replace the network ID with whatever is appropriate for your campus DHCP pool
2. Look for it in the arp cache: `arp -n` will display all addresses on the network that your computer knows about. Some devices have their MAC address (the first column in the arp table) printed on them physically. If not, you need to look at the first half of the MAC addresses from your arp table and see if any match the manufacturer of your device. I am not sure what vendor ID National Instruments use, but by phoning their tech support, they should be able to look this up for you, so that you don't have to do a vendor ID lookup on every device in your arp table.

Comment: Or just use the `arping` command with the devices MAC address as a parameter (and you don't need to to spam entire network with portscans).

Comment: @Marki555 `nmap -sP` isn't a portscan. It's a pingsweep.

Comment: Thanks! I am using mac os and windows. I tried to map the network like you said, however I can only get acces to MAC adresses if the IPs are in the same ip range (same IP except last 3 digits) Sometimes when I boot the NI device the next day it still has old ip from yesterday while my laptop got a new one in different range. I have access to its MAC and host name, It has a webpage interface that i can access once i have the ip will all the information. Ideally I would like to find out its IP (wireless) from a wired network on the same domain. Would this be possible?